# What exactly happens when I install an android application?

Tags: android

My guess is that the contents of .apk package are extracted somewhere, and the application is registered at some directory so that the application launcher or whatever can find it. But is that all? If that is the case, is the original manifest.xml read every time the app is launched or it gets pre-processed into some other form?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**: This answer is now 10 years old . While overall probably still accurate, details have definitely changed (ART instead of Dalvik, dynamic vs. static permissions, etc). Take it with a grain of salt!

### Some basics

#### The `.apk`-file

An `.apk`-file is not magical at all. It's just a bundle of files which represent the content of an Android application. If you open it in a archive-tool (like 7Zip), you can browser and extract it's contents.

#### Android is Linux

The basic Android-System is a Linux system. Android uses a custom Linux kernel with some extra functionality on power-saving and some speed-improvements. The internal storage of an Android device is formatted with the [YAFFS2-filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAFFS), which fully features the Linux-like access-concepts.

The used file-system might differ by manufacture or Android-Version. Newer devices often use `ext3`, while Samsung uses it's own file-system: [RFS](http://movitool.ntd.homelinux.org/trac/movitool/wiki/RFS)

This is one important aspect of the Sandbox-system, which is used by Android.

### Compiling applications

#### What happens to the `.java`-files?

First, they are compiled by the normal Java compiler. After they are compiled (to `.class`-files), the `dx`-tool from the Android SDK then converts/transpiles those "normal" java-classes into *Dalvik-Bytecode*.

This "special" java-code is then interpreted by the DVM (Dalvik Virtual Machine), which is based on the opensource JRE-implementation [Apache Harmony](http://harmony.apache.org/).

**Update**: In newer versions of Android, the convert/transpile step can be skipped when [jack](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html) is used. This way, the `.java` files are directly compiled into the `.dx` format.

Also, since version 4.4 (KitKat) Android has the new [ART runtime](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/), which officially replaced Dalvik in Android 5 (Lollipop).

#### What happens to the resources i put into the `/asset`-directory?

Android offers the `/assets`-directory to add some binary raw-files (e.g. a SQLite Database). Files which are put into this directory **are not** compiled or optimized.

If you put your files into this directory, this is the kind of behavior you would expect from Android.

#### What happens to the resources i put into the `/res/raw`-directory?

Like the `/assets`-directory, you can also put binary (or other) raw-files in here (e.g. HTML-files for the Help-page). These files **are** compiled/optimized (if possible).

#### What happens to the Manifest and the other XML-files?

The Android-Manifest and also the other XML-files (Layouts, Strings, etc.) are stored and "compiled" into a binary XML-format. This is a speed-optimization.

### The Sandbox

From Android OS point of view, a single Application owns:

- it's own process,
- it's own OS-User (like on Linux),
- it's own DVM,
- it's own place in the heap and
- it's own place on the filesystem.

So yes, every Android app has it's own user which has the proper rights to access it's place in the internal storage (which is protected by standard Linux filesystem rights-management) and it's own DVM-process (which can't be accessed from outside of the application).

To give the application the possibility to leave the Sandbox (e.g. to connect to the Internet), the permissions declared in the Android Manifest are used.

### Steps during the installation

So from the above explanations, it should be clear what happens when an Android-Application is installed:

1. The new user for the Application is created.
2. With this new users rights, the Applications directory in the internal storage is created.
3. The contents of the `.apk`-file are being extracted there.
4. The Android-Manifest is parsed and the declared `intent-filter`s are registered (e.g. the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`-filter for the applications standard entry point).
5. Now the application is ready for it's first launch.

Comment: On newer devices ext3 is used instead of YAFFS

Comment: Sorry, I should have thought of that. I added it to my answer.

Comment: I don't see any contents of my .apk appear in /data/data/{app}/**. "The contents of the .apk-file are being extracted there." - can someone tell me where exactly are they extracted to?

Comment: @Tapemaster I guess it might be dependent on your devices version/vendor, but at some point the should be there. Also, I'm not sure if an application can be installed to the SD card (rather than installing it and the moving). Lastly, do you have root access on the device? It might just be that your file-explorer can't access the folder (it shouldn't be able to if you don't have root) and is therefore showing an empty directory.

Comment: I have different kind of devices, rooted and non-rooted. With debuggable and release types of apps I have never noticed resources extracted to /data/data/{app}. Can you provide the file structure you see for the resources extracted in your case? Just file and directory names should do it.

Comment: @Tapemaster so I found this, which is a little more extensive on the whole Filesystem thing: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46926/android-folder-hierarchy I myself don't have a rooted phone here, so my `/data`-folder appears empty in my File-Explorer.

Comment: So, I take it as resource from .apk are not extracted during installation. You can see it even on not rooted device if you create the debuggable app - you'll be able to "run-as com.my.app" and see that resources are not there.

Comment: @Tapemaster what specific resources are you looking for? I know that at least the XML files are "pre-compiled" into a binary XML format.

Comment: @LukasKnuth, "I know that at least the XML files are "pre-compiled" into a binary XML format." - this is true. They are pre-compiled and zipped into an apk. But the point is, during installation they are not extracted into /data/data/...

Answer (score 3):

When you install an app, Android System copies its APK to "/data/app" folder and it named it by the package name followed by the installations number (how many times you install or update the app).

I tried to install an app manually by copying its APK and paste it in the /data/app folder and rebooted my device then it appears as an installed app and  works perfectly.

Also I noticed in the [link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en) app that any installed app has the folowing:

Apk located in   /data/app/package-number.apk

Dex located in   /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@package-number.apk@classes.dex

Lib located in   /data/data/package/lib

Data located in   /data/data/package

Cache located in   /data/data/package/cache

Answer (score 1):

Android defines an intent as "an abstract description of an operation to be performed." Not only do intents let you use activities made by others, but they are also used to launch applications. I'm sure you've seen these lines in every app you've written:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This intent filter allows the launcher to find the starting activity of each app. Lookup "intent resolution" for more details on this process... I'd say it's more elegant than simply registering the application at some random directory.

As stated in, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html, "Android system populates the application launcher, the top-level screen that shows the applications that are available for the user to launch, by finding all the activities with intent filters that specify the "android.intent.action.MAIN" action and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" category. It then displays the icons and labels of those activities in the launcher"