# APK loading workflow documentation

Tags: android

Is there any documentation where I can find how exactly an APK is loaded, which components are called and with which params? I'm interested in the zygote and how the DVM receives an APK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly happens when I install an android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773360/what-exactly-happens-when-i-install-an-android-application)

Comment: well the answer is not enough deep or tech. I'm more interested in how the dex file ends on the DVM. Which function are called, where the memory are reserved, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation on that, because it is not a public API. It is implementation details which means it can change at any moment.

Though the best thing you can do is to look into the code of the platform.

When the intent of your app is called for example because you tapped icon in a launcher, the system identifies that it belongs to your app, first it needs to figure out if the Application object is already created. If it's not - make it. It does it using reflection by using class loader which is a member of the context classes.

Look at LoadedApk.java

`if (mApplication != null) {
    return mApplication;
}
...
java.lang.ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();
app = mActivityThread.mInstrumentation.newApplication(
        cl, appClass, appContext);`

After application is created in my experience it also creating content providers, and finally the activity that is related to your intent.

Regarding your question about how the apk is used with DVM, I believe it is with the class ApplicationLoaders:

`PathClassLoader pathClassloader = new PathClassLoader(zip, libPath, parent);`

The DexClassLoader class accepts a file which is actually a zip with classes.dex in it. *LibPath* is a path to .so files and *parent* is a parent classloader - all the system stuff which is known to zygote upfront and which bootstrapped the whole thing in the first place.